# Does Wattpad have an API

Tags: api, wattpad

Does Wattpad offer any APIs for developers? I looked at their website but I didn't notice it mentioned anywhere.  I also saw that there are widgets that I can put on my website, but I'd like to build something beyond what they already have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclosure:** Wattpad Head of Product Here.

The API is available at http://developer.wattpad.com. 3 main parts to it:

- GET /stories - Search Wattpad stories and get story metadata
- Login with Wattpad - OAuth2 Login to your Wattpad account
- POST /stories - Post stories to Wattpad (this one is in alpha, launching soon).

There's also some other API's - all the docs are at http://developer.wattpad.com/docs/api.

New API docs are at: https://www.wattpad.com/developer/docs

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. This must be pretty new. I wasn't able to find anything about it when I looked for it awhile ago.

Comment: Hey! Can you please have a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295869/another-third-party-directing-developers-to-stackoverflow-for-tech-support-and-m real quick?

Comment: Thanks for posting this information. I have a customer who is curious about the possibility of integrating Wattpad with MarsEdit, my desktop blog editor for Mac. Unfortunately all the developer related links above seem to be dead now. Did Wattpad pull back on its developer resources?

Comment: I no longer work at there so I can't comment in an official capacity but my understanding is that Wattpad no longer has a developer program.